# using PHP urldecode function not working: Trying to Display the URL Encoded String in Human Readable Presentation, which I Read from a File

Tags: php, xampp, apache2.4, urldecode, php-8.2

my problem is PHP's built-in `urldecode()` function but I don't know why this is not working for me.

I'm using:

- XAMPP
- Server API    Apache 2.0 Handler
- Apache Version    Apache/2.4.56 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1t PHP/8.2.4
- PHP (PHP Version 8.2.4)
- OS Name   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
- Version   10.0.19045 Build 19045
- 

My PHP Code: (htdocs/php-tests/**url-decode.php**)

```
<?php

    ob_implicit_flush(true);
    $file = "../TankMonitorApp/cmds/showfile.rsp";
    $fp = readfile($file); // $fp: file pointer
    $output = "";
    $output = urldecode($fp);

    echo $output;

?>
```

The File I read: (htdocs/TankMonitorApp/cmds/**showfile.rsp**)

**showfile.rsp** (file contents)

```
filename=70:71:BC:71:04:15.d&filedata=
SECTION%3DHOST%0AMASTER-MINISERVER2.INTELLIFUEL.COM%0ASECTION%3DTIME%0AThu+Apr+24+13%3A18%3A02+UTC+2014%0A1398345482%0ASECTION%3DUPTIME%0A+13%3A18%3A02+up+84+days%2C+22%3A11%2C++0+users%2C++load+average%3A+0.02%2C+0.02%2C+0.00%0ASECTION%3DVERSION%0A2.1.3%0ASECTION%3DMODE%0AIP%0ASECTION%3DRAM%0A+++++++++++++total+++++++used+++++++free+++++shared++++buffers+++++cached%0AMem%3A+++++++2038328+++++910416++++1127912++++++++++0+++++195940+++++419148%0A-%2F%2B+buffers%2Fcache%3A+++++295328++++1743000%0ASwap%3A++++++2097144++++++++++0++++2097144%0ASECTION%3DDISK%0AFilesystem++++++++++++Size++Used+Avail+Use%25+Mounted+on%0A%2Fdev%2Fsda2++++++++++++++64G++3.5G+++58G+++6%25+%2F%0Atmpfs+++++++++++++++++996M+++++0++996M+++0%25+%2Fdev%2Fshm%0A%2Fdev%2Fsda1++++++++++++1008M+++73M++885M+++8%25+%2Fboot%0ASECTION%3DSTARTUP%0A%2Fetc%2Finit%2Fif_webadmin.conf%0ASECTION%3DCRONTAB%0A%23+set+the+password+of+the+day%0A%40reboot+%2Froot%2Fprogs%2Fconfigrestart+%3E+%2Froot%2Flogs%2Fconfigrestart.log+2%3E%261%0A0+%2A%2F4+%2A+%2A+%2A++%2Froot%2Fprogs%2Fconfigrestart+%3E+%2Froot%2Flogs%2Fconfigrestart.log+2%3E%261%0A%23+dialup+mode%0A%23%2A%2F3+%2A+%2A+%2A+%2A+%2Froot%2Fscripts%2Fwvdial.sh+%3E+%2Froot%2Flogs%2Fwvdial.log+2%3E%261%0A%23+ip+mode%0A0+4%2C11%2C16%2C20+%2A+%2A+%2A+%2Froot%2Fscripts%2Fmaint.sh+%3E+%2Froot%2Flogs%2Fmaint.log+2%3E%261%0A%23+all+modes+send+test+email%0A18%2C48+%2A+%2A+%2A+%2A+%2Froot%2Fscripts%2Fcheckforupdates.sh+%3E+%2Froot%2Flogs%2Fcheckforupdates.log+2%3E%261%0ASECTION%3DPROCESS%0AUSER+++++++PID+%25CPU+%25MEM++++VSZ+++RSS+TTY++++++STAT+START+++TIME+COMMAND%0Aroot+++++++++1++0.0++0.0++19236++1432+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++0%3A05+%2Fsbin%2Finit%0Aroot+++++++381++0.0++0.0++10692+++944+%3F++++++++S%3Cs++Jan29+++0%3A00+%2Fsbin%2Fudevd+-d%0Aroot++++++1025++0.0++0.0+++6060+++392+%3F++++++++S++++Jan29+++3%3A58+%2Fsbin%2Fifplugd+-i+eth0+-fwI+-u0+-d10%0Aroot++++++1085++0.0++0.0+248588++1496+%3F++++++++Sl+++Jan29+++1%3A24+%2Fsbin%2Frsyslogd+-c+4%0Arpc+++++++1139++0.0++0.0++18872+++860+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++0%3A06+rpcbind%0Arpcuser+++1158++0.0++0.0++23040++1164+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++0%3A00+rpc.statd%0Aroot++++++1171++0.0++0.0+++6556+++264+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++0%3A00+mdadm+--monitor+--scan+-f+--pid-file%3D%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fmdadm%2Fmdadm.pid%0Aroot++++++1204++0.0++0.0++29360+++540+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++0%3A00+rpc.idmapd%0Adbus++++++1233++0.0++0.0++21428++1080+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++0%3A05+dbus-daemon+--system%0Aavahi+++++1245++0.0++0.0++27648+++376+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++0%3A00+avahi-daemon%3A+chroot+helper%0Aroot++++++1255++0.0++0.1+178536++3232+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++0%3A00+cupsd+-C+%2Fetc%2Fcups%2Fcupsd.conf%0Aroot++++++1280++0.0++0.0+++3988+++616+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++0%3A00+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Facpid%0A68++++++++1289++0.0++0.2++25572++4348+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++0%3A52+hald%0Aroot++++++1290++0.0++0.0++18020++1132+%3F++++++++S++++Jan29+++0%3A00+hald-runner%0Aroot++++++1327++0.0++0.0++20136++1064+%3F++++++++S++++Jan29+++0%3A00+hald-addon-input%3A+Listening+on+%2Fdev%2Finput%2Fevent0+%2Fdev%2Finput%2Fevent1%0A68++++++++1334++0.0++0.0++17712++1004+%3F++++++++S++++Jan29+++0%3A00+hald-addon-acpi%3A+listening+on+acpid+socket+%2Fvar%2Frun%2Facpid.socket%0Aroot++++++1359++0.0++0.0++10688+++860+%3F++++++++S%3C+++Jan29+++0%3A00+%2Fsbin%2Fudevd+-d%0Aroot++++++1360++0.0++0.0++10688+++840+%3F++++++++S%3C+++Jan29+++0%3A00+%2Fsbin%2Fudevd+-d%0Aroot++++++1365++0.0++0.0+385592++1720+%3F++++++++Ssl++Jan29+++3%3A06+automount+--pid-file+%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fautofs.pid%0Antp+++++++1396++0.0++0.0++30048++1604+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++0%3A05+ntpd+-u+ntp%3Antp+-p+%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fntpd.pid+-g%0Aroot++++++1432++0.0++0.0+108112++1436+%3F++++++++S++++Jan29+++0%3A00+%2Fbin%2Fsh+%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Fmysqld_safe+--datadir%3D%2Fvar%2Flib%2Fmysql+--socket%3D%2Fvar%2Flib%2Fmysql%2Fmysql.sock+--pid-file%3D%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fmysqld%2Fmysqld.pid+--basedir%3D%2Fusr+--user%3Dmysql%0Amysql+++++1521++0.0++1.1+377248+24020+%3F++++++++Sl+++Jan29++51%3A23+%2Fusr%2Flibexec%2Fmysqld+--basedir%3D%2Fusr+--datadir%3D%2Fvar%2Flib%2Fmysql+--user%3Dmysql+--log-error%3D%2Fvar%2Flog%2Fmysqld.log+--pid-file%3D%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fmysqld%2Fmysqld.pid+--socket%3D%2Fvar%2Flib%2Fmysql%2Fmysql.sock%0Aroot++++++1618++0.0++0.1++61968++2696+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++0%3A01+%2Fusr%2Flibexec%2Fpostfix%2Fmaster%0Apostfix+++1627++0.0++0.1++62220++2812+%3F++++++++S++++Jan29+++0%3A00+qmgr+-l+-t+fifo+-u%0Aroot++++++1629++0.0++0.2+260188++4868+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++0%3A19+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fabrtd%0Aroot++++++1641++0.0++0.1++39076++2644+%3F++++++++S++++Jan29+++0%3A00+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fnss_pcache+off+%2Fetc%2Fhttpd%2Falias%0Aroot++++++1643++0.0++3.7+665184+76932+%3F++++++++Ssl++Jan29+++4%3A20+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fhttpd%0Aroot++++++1653++0.0++0.0+108500++1116+%3F++++++++S++++Jan29++10%3A19+%2Fbin%2Fbash+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fksmtuned%0Aroot++++++1663++0.0++0.0+117104++1284+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++1%3A17+crond%0Aroot++++++1676++0.0++0.0++21312+++460+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++0%3A00+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fatd%0Aroot++++++1693++0.0++0.6+280600+12476+%3F++++++++Sl+++Jan29+++0%3A01+libvirtd+--daemon%0Anobody++++1794++0.0++0.0++12792+++536+%3F++++++++S++++Jan29+++0%3A00+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fdnsmasq+--strict-order+--bind-interfaces+--pid-file%3D%2Fvar%2Frun%2Flibvirt%2Fnetwork%2Fdefault.pid+--conf-file%3D++--listen-address+192.168.122.1+--except-interface+lo+--dhcp-range+192.168.122.2%2C192.168.122.254+--dhcp-lease-max%3D253+--dhcp-no-override%0Aroot++++++1857++0.0++0.7+298376+15600+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29++67%3A37+%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Fphp+%2Froot%2Fprogs%2Fwebadmin.php%0Aroot++++++1862++0.0++0.0+++3972+++516+tty1+++++Ss%2B++Jan29+++0%3A00+%2Fsbin%2Fmingetty+%2Fdev%2Ftty1%0Aroot++++++1864++0.0++0.0+++3972+++520+tty2+++++Ss%2B++Jan29+++0%3A00+%2Fsbin%2Fmingetty+%2Fdev%2Ftty2%0Aroot++++++1866++0.0++0.0+++3972+++520+tty3+++++Ss%2B++Jan29+++0%3A00+%2Fsbin%2Fmingetty+%2Fdev%2Ftty3%0Aroot++++++1868++0.0++0.0+++3972+++520+tty4+++++Ss%2B++Jan29+++0%3A00+%2Fsbin%2Fmingetty+%2Fdev%2Ftty4%0Aroot++++++1870++0.0++0.0+++3972+++520+tty5+++++Ss%2B++Jan29+++0%3A00+%2Fsbin%2Fmingetty+%2Fdev%2Ftty5%0Aroot++++++1872++0.0++0.0+++3972+++516+tty6+++++Ss%2B++Jan29+++0%3A00+%2Fsbin%2Fmingetty+%2Fdev%2Ftty6%0Aroot++++++1897++0.0++0.0++93072+++892+%3F++++++++S%3Csl+Jan29+++2%3A11+auditd%0Aapache++++5218++0.0++1.0+665184+20856+%3F++++++++S++++Apr20+++0%3A00+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fhttpd%0Aapache++++5219++0.0++1.4+693832+29404+%3F++++++++S++++Apr20+++0%3A00+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fhttpd%0Aapache++++5220++0.0++1.4+693832+29404+%3F++++++++S++++Apr20+++0%3A00+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fhttpd%0Aapache++++5221++0.0++1.4+693832+29404+%3F++++++++S++++Apr20+++0%3A00+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fhttpd%0Aapache++++5222++0.0++1.4+693832+29404+%3F++++++++S++++Apr20+++0%3A00+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fhttpd%0Aapache++++5223++0.0++1.4+693832+29404+%3F++++++++S++++Apr20+++0%3A00+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fhttpd%0Aapache++++5224++0.0++1.4+693832+29400+%3F++++++++S++++Apr20+++0%3A00+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fhttpd%0Aapache++++5225++0.0++1.4+693832+29404+%3F++++++++S++++Apr20+++0%3A00+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fhttpd%0Aapache++++5226++0.0++1.4+693832+29404+%3F++++++++S++++Apr20+++0%3A00+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fhttpd%0Aroot++++++6470++0.0++0.0++63756++1280+%3F++++++++Ss+++11%3A00+++0%3A00+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fsshd%0Apostfix+++7895++0.0++0.1++62048++2668+%3F++++++++S++++11%3A46+++0%3A00+pickup+-l+-t+fifo+-u%0Aroot+++++10762++0.0++0.0+100816+++540+%3F++++++++S++++13%3A17+++0%3A00+sleep+60%0Aroot+++++10770++0.0++0.0+139948++1696+%3F++++++++S++++13%3A18+++0%3A00+CROND%0Aroot+++++10771++0.0++0.0+++9144++1032+%3F++++++++Ss+++13%3A18+++0%3A00+%2Fbin%2Fsh+-c+%2Froot%2Fscripts%2Fcheckforupdates.sh+%3E+%2Froot%2Flogs%2Fcheckforupdates.log+2%3E%261%0Aroot+++++10772++0.0++0.0+++9148++1144+%3F++++++++S++++13%3A18+++0%3A00+%2Fbin%2Fsh+%2Froot%2Fscripts%2Fcheckforupdates.sh%0Aroot+++++10794++0.0++0.0+++9148++1136+%3F++++++++S++++13%3A18+++0%3A00+%2Fbin%2Fsh+%2Froot%2Fscripts%2Fsysstat%0Aroot+++++10809++2.0++0.0++11104+++928+%3F++++++++R++++13%3A18+++0%3A00+ps+uax%0ASECTION%3DINFO%0ABase+Board+Information%0A%09Manufacturer%3A+Intel+Corporation%0A%09Product+Name%3A+D410PT%0A%09Version%3A+AAE76528-404%0A%09Serial+Number%3A+BTPT0300059Y%0AProcessor+Information%0A%09Socket+Designation%3A+U1PR%0A%09Type%3A+Central+Processor%0A%09Family%3A+Other%0A%09Manufacturer%3A+Intel%28R%29+Corporation%0A%09ID%3A+CA+06+01+00+FF+FB+EB+BF%0A%09Version%3A+Intel%28R%29+Atom%28TM%29+CPU+D410+++%40+1.66GHz%0A%09Voltage%3A+1.1+V%0A
```

My HTML output: (It's same as before I use `urldecode()` function call in **url-decode.php** line: 7 )

```
filename=70:71:BC:71:04:15.d&filedata=
SECTION%3DHOST%0AMASTER-MINISERVER2.INTELLIFUEL.COM%0ASECTION%3DTIME%0AThu+Apr+24+13%3A18%3A02+UTC+2014%0A1398345482%0ASECTION%3DUPTIME%0A+13%3A18%3A02+up+84+days%2C+22%3A11%2C++0+users%2C++load+average%3A+0.02%2C+0.02%2C+0.00%0ASECTION%3DVERSION%0A2.1.3%0ASECTION%3DMODE%0AIP%0ASECTION%3DRAM%0A+++++++++++++total+++++++used+++++++free+++++shared++++buffers+++++cached%0AMem%3A+++++++2038328+++++910416++++1127912++++++++++0+++++195940+++++419148%0A-%2F%2B+buffers%2Fcache%3A+++++295328++++1743000%0ASwap%3A++++++2097144++++++++++0++++2097144%0ASECTION%3DDISK%0AFilesystem++++++++++++Size++Used+Avail+Use%25+Mounted+on%0A%2Fdev%2Fsda2++++++++++++++64G++3.5G+++58G+++6%25+%2F%0Atmpfs+++++++++++++++++996M+++++0++996M+++0%25+%2Fdev%2Fshm%0A%2Fdev%2Fsda1++++++++++++1008M+++73M++885M+++8%25+%2Fboot%0ASECTION%3DSTARTUP%0A%2Fetc%2Finit%2Fif_webadmin.conf%0ASECTION%3DCRONTAB%0A%23+set+the+password+of+the+day%0A%40reboot+%2Froot%2Fprogs%2Fconfigrestart+%3E+%2Froot%2Flogs%2Fconfigrestart.log+2%3E%261%0A0+%2A%2F4+%2A+%2A+%2A++%2Froot%2Fprogs%2Fconfigrestart+%3E+%2Froot%2Flogs%2Fconfigrestart.log+2%3E%261%0A%23+dialup+mode%0A%23%2A%2F3+%2A+%2A+%2A+%2A+%2Froot%2Fscripts%2Fwvdial.sh+%3E+%2Froot%2Flogs%2Fwvdial.log+2%3E%261%0A%23+ip+mode%0A0+4%2C11%2C16%2C20+%2A+%2A+%2A+%2Froot%2Fscripts%2Fmaint.sh+%3E+%2Froot%2Flogs%2Fmaint.log+2%3E%261%0A%23+all+modes+send+test+email%0A18%2C48+%2A+%2A+%2A+%2A+%2Froot%2Fscripts%2Fcheckforupdates.sh+%3E+%2Froot%2Flogs%2Fcheckforupdates.log+2%3E%261%0ASECTION%3DPROCESS%0AUSER+++++++PID+%25CPU+%25MEM++++VSZ+++RSS+TTY++++++STAT+START+++TIME+COMMAND%0Aroot+++++++++1++0.0++0.0++19236++1432+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++0%3A05+%2Fsbin%2Finit%0Aroot+++++++381++0.0++0.0++10692+++944+%3F++++++++S%3Cs++Jan29+++0%3A00+%2Fsbin%2Fudevd+-d%0Aroot++++++1025++0.0++0.0+++6060+++392+%3F++++++++S++++Jan29+++3%3A58+%2Fsbin%2Fifplugd+-i+eth0+-fwI+-u0+-d10%0Aroot++++++1085++0.0++0.0+248588++1496+%3F++++++++Sl+++Jan29+++1%3A24+%2Fsbin%2Frsyslogd+-c+4%0Arpc+++++++1139++0.0++0.0++18872+++860+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++0%3A06+rpcbind%0Arpcuser+++1158++0.0++0.0++23040++1164+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++0%3A00+rpc.statd%0Aroot++++++1171++0.0++0.0+++6556+++264+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++0%3A00+mdadm+--monitor+--scan+-f+--pid-file%3D%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fmdadm%2Fmdadm.pid%0Aroot++++++1204++0.0++0.0++29360+++540+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++0%3A00+rpc.idmapd%0Adbus++++++1233++0.0++0.0++21428++1080+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++0%3A05+dbus-daemon+--system%0Aavahi+++++1245++0.0++0.0++27648+++376+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++0%3A00+avahi-daemon%3A+chroot+helper%0Aroot++++++1255++0.0++0.1+178536++3232+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++0%3A00+cupsd+-C+%2Fetc%2Fcups%2Fcupsd.conf%0Aroot++++++1280++0.0++0.0+++3988+++616+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++0%3A00+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Facpid%0A68++++++++1289++0.0++0.2++25572++4348+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++0%3A52+hald%0Aroot++++++1290++0.0++0.0++18020++1132+%3F++++++++S++++Jan29+++0%3A00+hald-runner%0Aroot++++++1327++0.0++0.0++20136++1064+%3F++++++++S++++Jan29+++0%3A00+hald-addon-input%3A+Listening+on+%2Fdev%2Finput%2Fevent0+%2Fdev%2Finput%2Fevent1%0A68++++++++1334++0.0++0.0++17712++1004+%3F++++++++S++++Jan29+++0%3A00+hald-addon-acpi%3A+listening+on+acpid+socket+%2Fvar%2Frun%2Facpid.socket%0Aroot++++++1359++0.0++0.0++10688+++860+%3F++++++++S%3C+++Jan29+++0%3A00+%2Fsbin%2Fudevd+-d%0Aroot++++++1360++0.0++0.0++10688+++840+%3F++++++++S%3C+++Jan29+++0%3A00+%2Fsbin%2Fudevd+-d%0Aroot++++++1365++0.0++0.0+385592++1720+%3F++++++++Ssl++Jan29+++3%3A06+automount+--pid-file+%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fautofs.pid%0Antp+++++++1396++0.0++0.0++30048++1604+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++0%3A05+ntpd+-u+ntp%3Antp+-p+%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fntpd.pid+-g%0Aroot++++++1432++0.0++0.0+108112++1436+%3F++++++++S++++Jan29+++0%3A00+%2Fbin%2Fsh+%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Fmysqld_safe+--datadir%3D%2Fvar%2Flib%2Fmysql+--socket%3D%2Fvar%2Flib%2Fmysql%2Fmysql.sock+--pid-file%3D%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fmysqld%2Fmysqld.pid+--basedir%3D%2Fusr+--user%3Dmysql%0Amysql+++++1521++0.0++1.1+377248+24020+%3F++++++++Sl+++Jan29++51%3A23+%2Fusr%2Flibexec%2Fmysqld+--basedir%3D%2Fusr+--datadir%3D%2Fvar%2Flib%2Fmysql+--user%3Dmysql+--log-error%3D%2Fvar%2Flog%2Fmysqld.log+--pid-file%3D%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fmysqld%2Fmysqld.pid+--socket%3D%2Fvar%2Flib%2Fmysql%2Fmysql.sock%0Aroot++++++1618++0.0++0.1++61968++2696+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++0%3A01+%2Fusr%2Flibexec%2Fpostfix%2Fmaster%0Apostfix+++1627++0.0++0.1++62220++2812+%3F++++++++S++++Jan29+++0%3A00+qmgr+-l+-t+fifo+-u%0Aroot++++++1629++0.0++0.2+260188++4868+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++0%3A19+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fabrtd%0Aroot++++++1641++0.0++0.1++39076++2644+%3F++++++++S++++Jan29+++0%3A00+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fnss_pcache+off+%2Fetc%2Fhttpd%2Falias%0Aroot++++++1643++0.0++3.7+665184+76932+%3F++++++++Ssl++Jan29+++4%3A20+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fhttpd%0Aroot++++++1653++0.0++0.0+108500++1116+%3F++++++++S++++Jan29++10%3A19+%2Fbin%2Fbash+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fksmtuned%0Aroot++++++1663++0.0++0.0+117104++1284+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++1%3A17+crond%0Aroot++++++1676++0.0++0.0++21312+++460+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29+++0%3A00+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fatd%0Aroot++++++1693++0.0++0.6+280600+12476+%3F++++++++Sl+++Jan29+++0%3A01+libvirtd+--daemon%0Anobody++++1794++0.0++0.0++12792+++536+%3F++++++++S++++Jan29+++0%3A00+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fdnsmasq+--strict-order+--bind-interfaces+--pid-file%3D%2Fvar%2Frun%2Flibvirt%2Fnetwork%2Fdefault.pid+--conf-file%3D++--listen-address+192.168.122.1+--except-interface+lo+--dhcp-range+192.168.122.2%2C192.168.122.254+--dhcp-lease-max%3D253+--dhcp-no-override%0Aroot++++++1857++0.0++0.7+298376+15600+%3F++++++++Ss+++Jan29++67%3A37+%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Fphp+%2Froot%2Fprogs%2Fwebadmin.php%0Aroot++++++1862++0.0++0.0+++3972+++516+tty1+++++Ss%2B++Jan29+++0%3A00+%2Fsbin%2Fmingetty+%2Fdev%2Ftty1%0Aroot++++++1864++0.0++0.0+++3972+++520+tty2+++++Ss%2B++Jan29+++0%3A00+%2Fsbin%2Fmingetty+%2Fdev%2Ftty2%0Aroot++++++1866++0.0++0.0+++3972+++520+tty3+++++Ss%2B++Jan29+++0%3A00+%2Fsbin%2Fmingetty+%2Fdev%2Ftty3%0Aroot++++++1868++0.0++0.0+++3972+++520+tty4+++++Ss%2B++Jan29+++0%3A00+%2Fsbin%2Fmingetty+%2Fdev%2Ftty4%0Aroot++++++1870++0.0++0.0+++3972+++520+tty5+++++Ss%2B++Jan29+++0%3A00+%2Fsbin%2Fmingetty+%2Fdev%2Ftty5%0Aroot++++++1872++0.0++0.0+++3972+++516+tty6+++++Ss%2B++Jan29+++0%3A00+%2Fsbin%2Fmingetty+%2Fdev%2Ftty6%0Aroot++++++1897++0.0++0.0++93072+++892+%3F++++++++S%3Csl+Jan29+++2%3A11+auditd%0Aapache++++5218++0.0++1.0+665184+20856+%3F++++++++S++++Apr20+++0%3A00+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fhttpd%0Aapache++++5219++0.0++1.4+693832+29404+%3F++++++++S++++Apr20+++0%3A00+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fhttpd%0Aapache++++5220++0.0++1.4+693832+29404+%3F++++++++S++++Apr20+++0%3A00+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fhttpd%0Aapache++++5221++0.0++1.4+693832+29404+%3F++++++++S++++Apr20+++0%3A00+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fhttpd%0Aapache++++5222++0.0++1.4+693832+29404+%3F++++++++S++++Apr20+++0%3A00+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fhttpd%0Aapache++++5223++0.0++1.4+693832+29404+%3F++++++++S++++Apr20+++0%3A00+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fhttpd%0Aapache++++5224++0.0++1.4+693832+29400+%3F++++++++S++++Apr20+++0%3A00+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fhttpd%0Aapache++++5225++0.0++1.4+693832+29404+%3F++++++++S++++Apr20+++0%3A00+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fhttpd%0Aapache++++5226++0.0++1.4+693832+29404+%3F++++++++S++++Apr20+++0%3A00+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fhttpd%0Aroot++++++6470++0.0++0.0++63756++1280+%3F++++++++Ss+++11%3A00+++0%3A00+%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fsshd%0Apostfix+++7895++0.0++0.1++62048++2668+%3F++++++++S++++11%3A46+++0%3A00+pickup+-l+-t+fifo+-u%0Aroot+++++10762++0.0++0.0+100816+++540+%3F++++++++S++++13%3A17+++0%3A00+sleep+60%0Aroot+++++10770++0.0++0.0+139948++1696+%3F++++++++S++++13%3A18+++0%3A00+CROND%0Aroot+++++10771++0.0++0.0+++9144++1032+%3F++++++++Ss+++13%3A18+++0%3A00+%2Fbin%2Fsh+-c+%2Froot%2Fscripts%2Fcheckforupdates.sh+%3E+%2Froot%2Flogs%2Fcheckforupdates.log+2%3E%261%0Aroot+++++10772++0.0++0.0+++9148++1144+%3F++++++++S++++13%3A18+++0%3A00+%2Fbin%2Fsh+%2Froot%2Fscripts%2Fcheckforupdates.sh%0Aroot+++++10794++0.0++0.0+++9148++1136+%3F++++++++S++++13%3A18+++0%3A00+%2Fbin%2Fsh+%2Froot%2Fscripts%2Fsysstat%0Aroot+++++10809++2.0++0.0++11104+++928+%3F++++++++R++++13%3A18+++0%3A00+ps+uax%0ASECTION%3DINFO%0ABase+Board+Information%0A%09Manufacturer%3A+Intel+Corporation%0A%09Product+Name%3A+D410PT%0A%09Version%3A+AAE76528-404%0A%09Serial+Number%3A+BTPT0300059Y%0AProcessor+Information%0A%09Socket+Designation%3A+U1PR%0A%09Type%3A+Central+Processor%0A%09Family%3A+Other%0A%09Manufacturer%3A+Intel%28R%29+Corporation%0A%09ID%3A+CA+06+01+00+FF+FB+EB+BF%0A%09Version%3A+Intel%28R%29+Atom%28TM%29+CPU+D410+++%40+1.66GHz%0A%09Voltage%3A+1.1+V%0A8401
```

It's not working the way i expected it to work (talking about **`urldecode($fp)`** function call).

urldecode() function but i dont know why this is not working for me.

**What I expect:**
is that the File Contents are read from File, then everything read from File is assigned to a String variable **$fp**.

Then still when i urldecode it using builtin PHP function **`urldecode($fp)`**, it doesn't yield anything in Human Readable form/representation,
i.e.: as still %## hex characters aren't being replaced with actual characters.

which is totally unexpected as urldecode function should do as mentioned in Official PHP Documentation:

> urldecode
> (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7, PHP 8)
>
> urldecode — Decodes URL-encoded string
>
> Description ¶
> urldecode(string $string): string
> Decodes any %## encoding in the given string. Plus symbols ('+') are decoded to a space character.
>
> Parameters ¶
> string
> The string to be decoded.
>
> Return Values ¶
> Returns the decoded string.

Comment: `readfile()` doesn't do what you think it does. The function you want is `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: The argument to `urldecode()` must be a string, not a file pointer.

Comment: @Barmar, You're absolutely right. thank you for pointing me out in Right Direction.

Comment: But @Barmar, your solution is still not working. URL-Encoded String is still not being URL-Decoded.

When I view-source, I get the desired result.
But the result is actually required on Web Page directly, not when view-source command is used.

Am attaching the **files** for better understanding the scenario.

Comment: You should use `htmlspecialchars()` when displaying it on a web page, in case it contains HTML tags.